# Restore Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, gemfile

I deleted the gemfile.lock from my Redmine 2.2, installed in my machine. How can I restore it?

I tried "bundle install", without success.

Comment: What happens when you `bundle install`?  That should create the file again, unless something prevents it from writing the file for some reason.  Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, it's not a big deal.

Gemfile.lock is a snapshot of which version of a gem was installed, where it came from, and it's dependencies, for reasons of portability. Given that you are using [packaged software](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/tree/2.2-stable), unless you plan to distribute your code at some point in the future, lacking a Gemfile.lock is not the end of the world.

If you absolutely need a Gemfile.lock file, try **changing your Gemfile** and running `bundle install` again. Bundler installs a gem if it cannot find it already cached or installed. Since you are trying to install a fully-installed set of gems, Bundler may be glossing over the entire process without performing any work. Give it something to do by installing an arbitrary gem you don't already have, then maybe it will generate a new Gemfile.lock file for you.

Or I suppose the easiest way is to **delete your entire gems folder** then run `bundle install`. This is equivalent to starting over with a clean install, without nuking your data set.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using version control? If you are try `git reset --hard`. Otherwise, no one can help you...